# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The problem is solved by restarting the application in biztalk

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

Consider the following error message:

```
Timestamp: 9/11/2018 3:09:34 PM
Message: Class: XXX.MW.BackEnds.oTransaccoesSuspeitas Method: Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.StopConditions segment7(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.StopConditions) : Exception: An error occurred while processing the message, refer to the details section for more information 
Message ID: {139DCE33-4627-4103-9B25-1906EBAD14A8}
Instance ID: {1F943998-158C-4357-8E2A-0473B9425CD3}
Error Description: System.Net.WebException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
401 UNAUTHORIZED
 Stack Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
Category: Critical
Priority: 4
EventId: 0
Severity: Critical
Title:XXX.MW.BackEnds, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1512f695a673d231
Machine: CORE04
Application Domain: __XDomain_3.0.1.0_0
Process Id: 54889
Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\BTSNTSvc.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 7844
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties: Exception - Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.XlangSoapException: An error occurred while processing the message, refer to the details section for more information 
Message ID: {139DCE33-4627-4103-9B25-1906EBAD14A8}
Instance ID: {1F943998-158C-4357-8E2A-0473B9425CD3}
Error Description: System.Net.WebException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
401 UNAUTHORIZED

   at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBase.VerifyTransport(Envelope env, Int32 operationId, Context ctx)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Subscription.Receive(Segment s, Context ctx, Envelope& env, Boolean topOnly)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PortBase.GetMessageId(Subscription subscription, Segment currentSegment, Context cxt, Envelope& env, CachedObject location)
   at XXX.MW.BackEnds.oTransaccoesSuspeitas.segment2(StopConditions stopOn)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)
```

The error is being thrown by an orchestration during the processing of a message obtained from an SQL table.

The data was obtained successfully because I have a readingIndex that's updated by biztalk.

The problem happens randomly, but I can fix it by restarting the biztalk application.

What could possibly be causing the problem?

Do I reset some identification code by restarting the applications?

Comment: How are you calling the SQL database, i.e. which adapter are you using?  Or are you calling SQL using a custom class?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Using wcf-sql to call the server