# How do I restart a biztalk application automatically?

Tags: biztalk

I want to restart a biztalk application automatically everyday. What's a good way to do it?
[image: My applications]

Comment: Well, why?   Restarting a app daily does not solve any problem.  If you describe why you're trying to do this, we can help you solve the real problem.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281932/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-ntlm-the-p)
I have that problem that seems hard to debug but gets quickfixed by application restarts. 
I've already found a way to restart the app through task scheduler and a powershell script so I'll answer the question on monday.